# Magento2 Welcome Email

Tags: magento2, email

I am unable to edit the CSS for the welcome email template in Magento2.

[image]

Please help me where to edit this.

Answer (score 3):

Extend your **Magento_Sales** module from Luma ( you are using ).  And make changes in  **_module.less/_email.less** as your required

From

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Sales/web/css/source/_module.less
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Sales/web/css/source/_module.less
```

After editing run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I hope this will help you out , let me know if any problem

Thanks